# Laravel join tables with JSON field, when some fields have no foreign key

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I want to join 2 tables by a foreign key stored in a JSON field. The field can be empty, so i get an error, i can not sem to get rid of.

I have a model `Transaction`:

```
class Transaction extends BaseModel
{
    protected $casts = [
        'items' => 'json',
    ];
```

the `items` field is json:

```
[{"event_id":25,"article_nr":"000123","title":"My Event"}]
```

now i want to join these tables for a query:

```
Transaction::join('events','transactions.items->event_id', '=', 'events.id')
->get();
```

The problem is, that i have many transaction types, so the items field does not necessarily contain the `event_id` key, or can even be empty.

The SQL query from Eloquent is:

```
select * from `transactions` inner join `events` on json_unquote(json_extract(`transactions`.`items`, '$."event_id"')) = `events`.`id`
```

So for rows with empty `items`-field i get the error:

```
3141 Invalid JSON text in argument 1 to function json_extract: "The document is empty." at position 0.
```

Is there a way to alter my join and only select rows, that contain the `items->event_id` key?

*[edit] added SQL raw query*

Comment: *or can even be empty* What is the value in this case PRECISELY.

Comment: an empty string

Comment: Replace with valid JSON. For example, an empty array.

Comment: nice, this looks better now. i dont get any errors. the result is still empty, but i think i can get over this. my syntax is wrong, i guess. thank you so much.

Comment: well, next problem: my item-objects are an array, if you look at the brackets in the data. eloquent translates it to `inner join events on json_unquote(json_extract(transactions.items, '$."[0]event_id"')) = events.id`, but i need `inner join events on json_unquote(json_extract(transactions.items, '$[0]."event_id"')) = events.id`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working...

After the help from Akina (thanks), who mentioned, that all fields have to be filled with at least an empty json object:

```
Update transactions set items = '{}' where items = '' or items is null;
```

I was able to join the tables with:

```
Transaction::select(['transactions.*'])
                ->leftJoin('events',DB::raw("json_extract(transactions.items, '$[0].event_id')"),"=","events.id")
```

The `'$[0].event_id'` part is special to this join, because i have my event_id in an object, and this object is in an array:

```
[{"event_id":24}]
```

(Notice the outer brackets)

Without the outer array it would be easy, and i could have just done it without raw sql, like:

```
Transaction::leftJoin('events','transactions.items->event_id', '=', 'events.id')
```

[EDIT]
**FINAL SOLUTION**

You will run into performance problems, when joining by JSON fields. My query took about 160s.

The final solution was to create a generated column `event_id` from the `items` row. The MySQL "generated column" is autofilled from its expression and automatically updated by MySQL/MariaDB, when the items field is updated.

```
ALTER TABLE transactions ADD event_id int(10) UNSIGNED AS (JSON_UNQUOTE(items->"$[0].event_id")) STORED;
```

The laravel migration for that would be

```
$table->bigInteger('event_id')->unsigned()->storedAs('JSON_UNQUOTE(items->"$[0].event_id")');
```

Now my query only takes 0.2s instead of 160s.